# psql: fatal role "root" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.3

I have gone through many SO question answer my problem was not solved..

This is the method I tried:

```
user@user-Latitude-XT3:~$ sudo su postgres
No passwd entry for user 'postgres'
user@user-Latitude-XT3:~$
```

and many others.

I keep on getting `fatal error user does not exist`

any working solution?

**please Note** before marking duplicate, tried all similar but wasn't solved yet.

Answer (score 26):

This is how I normally login to postgres:

```
sudo -i
sudo -i -u postgres
psql
```

**Edit:**

if you are using Debian

```
su postgres
psql
```

Answer (score 3):

Here how i fixed,

1. vi /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf
2. `local   all             postgres                                peer`

   here change **peer** to **trust**
3. restart, `sudo service postgresql restart`
4. now try, `psql -U postgres`

Comment: after step 4 I get: `psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't specify the user, psql will try to login with the current system logged in user. Try to add the user option (`-U`) to the psql command:

```
psql -U <existing role with permission>
```